# Delete specific IAM user from all the roles in a project/org using CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I delete a specific user from all the roles recursively - from a project or organization?

Something similar to :

```
gcloud projects remove-iam-policy-binding <prj id> --member user:testp@xyz.com
```

Without providing the --role?

Comment: This is the UI equivalent to the "Remove" button yes? Which says it `Are you sure you want to remove xxx? They will lose all roles on this resource.`

Answer (score 1):

Role is a [required flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/remove-iam-policy-binding#REQUIRED-FLAGS), you can't perform this command without it. You would have to go through all the roles the person had and remove them. This is easy to see on the IAM console page.

This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/security/data-loss-prevention/revoking-user-access#remove_the_account_from_project_membership) goes through all the things to consider when removing access from your project. You can delete the user via the console but also be aware of service accounts, client ID secrets, API keys, SSH keys, Cloud SQL access, Cloud Storage ACLs, BigQuery datasets and Pub/Sub topics.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can in one command.

However, a little bash or your favourite scripting language could easily make use of this command to get all roles. Iterate though each project ID if necessary too.

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT_ID}  \
  --flatten="bindings[].members" \
  --format="table(bindings.role)" \
  --filter="bindings.members:${USER}"
```

For each line,

```
gcloud projects remove-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} \
  --member="${USER}" \
  --role="roles/${ROLE}"
```